# converting audio bytes[] array to RTSP stream using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Thanks in adv,

I am creating a windows application where the goal is to receive bytes array from the stethoscope as input and convert them at runtime to RTSP stream 
 ffmpeg seems like the right tool for the conversion, but every command line
example I have seen takes a file as an input and converting into stream.my aim is I have an input of a byte array , and get an output of a
 RTSP stream.  Is it possible to convert  byte array to an RTSP stream through ffmpeg.

Comment: So, did you find something real? I need to convert input byte array to stream or other (encoded) byte array without saving to the file in the middle.